# ExhaustiveTemplateMatching ProcessImage return empty

Tags: c#, image, aforge

this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);

            // Compare two images
            System.Drawing.Bitmap image1 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("2.jpg");
            System.Drawing.Bitmap image2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("2.jpg");
            TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(image1, image2);
            MessageBox.Show(matchings[0].Similarity.ToString());
            // Check similarity level
            if (matchings[0].Similarity > 0.95)
            {

            }
        }
```

attchment:

[value and exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtmW2.png)

[value and exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQhwz.png)

Comment: Please do read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado can you give me a help on this question ?thanks

Comment: Index out of range exception is due to the fact that `matchings` doesn't contain any elements. You might want to find the cause inside `TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(image1, image2);`. I highly suggest you learn how to put break points and debug your application. You'd be surprise that sometimes a simple mistake in coding is causing your application to fail.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado you are right ,the root cause is the  matchings is empty ,i am looking for why it happened ,I have tried other pictures ,it's ok, not always fail.now i am checking aforge source code , have not get any useful info.

Comment: You should indicate in your post that `ExhaustiveTemplateMatching ` is not yours. Post every relevant information when asking a question here in SO. Someone who knows the answer might have overlooked this question because of the lack of information.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado i have find the root cause ,the data overflow，int type is not enough ,my head is biger and biger

Answer (score 0):

the final solution is to rewrite ExhaustiveTemplateMatching class to change value type ,because the pic resolution is so big that int32 value is not enough